# Initialization of a pointer to an array of objects

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers

I intended to initialize a pointer to an array of objects of the class 'Port.h'. To do so, first a pointer of type 'Port' is initialized, then  the constructor of this class is called for every element of the array.

```
int main(){
   Port *ports;

   for (int m = 0; m < M; m++){
       // Initialize
       ports[m] = Port(***PARAMETERS***);
       // ...
   }
   // ...
}
```

I am getting the following error when running the code:

***error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'ports' used***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you could start loading pointers into your array, you need to initialize the array itself:

```
Port *ports = new Port[M];
```

However, your class lacks default constructor, so the above declaration will not work. You could make an array of pointers instead, and use it like this:

```
Port **ports = new Port*[M];
```

When you put data into the array of pointers, you need to use operator `new`:

```
ports[m] = new Port(***PARAMETERS***);
//         ^^^
```

Since `ports` holds pointers now, you need to use pointer syntax to access `Port`'s members:

```
ports[m]->memberFunction(param1, param2); // Note the use of '->' in place of a dot '.'
```

Once you are done working with the array, you need to `delete` the individual `Port` objects, and then `delete[]` the `ports` array to avoid memory leaks:

```
for (int m = 0 ; m != M ; m++) {
    delete ports[m];
}
delete[] ports;
```

Note: much code is dedicated to management of memory now. To avoid having to write this code, use standard collections and smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you should allocate a zone for that pointer:

```
 #define M 15 /* or whatever you want */
 Port *ports = new Port[M];
```

Don't forget to `delete`the array later, perhaps by ending your `main` with

```
 delete[] ports;
```

---

But I believe you should not use a pointer to an array zone, but a vector, e.g.

```
 std::vector<Port> ports;
```

Read more about  [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You probably want to call its `resize` or its `push_back` or [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) methods (assuming [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11)). So if you can construct some `Port(12,"abc");` you would call:

```
 ports.emplace_back(12,"abc");
```

to construct and add such a port at the end of your `ports` vector.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will consider using vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear enough: variable ports was not initialized

```
Port *ports;
```

So it has any arbitrary value.

You need to allocate memory for the array that you are going to use. For example

```
Port *ports = new Port[M];
```

And it would be better if instead of the dynamically allocated array you would use class std::vector. For example

```
std::vector<Port> ports( M, Port(***PARAMETERS***) );
```